# How company-mode suggestions are delivered?

Tags: company-mode

I am curios whether there exist a side-channel possibilities for emacs `company-mode`.

I thought, since company-mode suggests words that matches the given prefix, the suggestions may leak some sort of information of what is being typed.

Since I am a complete novice to emacs source code, I want to see how company mode is working internally...

Where can be the best starting point to look at the source tree?

Comment: You might want to develop a proper threat model before investigating any further. Suppose someone had access to that Emacs session, they could just install a hook that logs the pressed keys. No need to look at what company-mode displays, unless you define your attacker only able of shoulder-surfing (in which case, why can't they just look at the keyboard?).

Answer (score 0):

company-mode is not part of Emacs, it's independently developed on GitHub: https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode

Comment: (This answers the part of the question about the location of the source code.)